# unable to play media with AVPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa

I am trying to play mp3 and other audio formats stored on a server with AVPlayer, but every time I get error EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
However, I am able to play these audio files on the browser on chrome.
My Code is in viewDidLoad like this

```
AVPlayerViewController *playerController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
AVPlayer *songPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mplayer.example.com/Recordings/sun.mp3"]];
playerController.player = songPlayer;
playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame;
[playerController.view sizeToFit];
playerController.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;
playerController.showsPlaybackControls = YES;
[songPlayer play];
[self.view insertSubview:playerController.view atIndex:0];
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with my code because my URL is correct and I can fetch audio files from this URL.

Comment: Add exception breakpoint and check on which line its crashing.

Comment: Your provided url show me this messages "This webpage is not available"

Comment: I'd start with retaining `playerController` by adding it as a child view controller (`[self addChildViewController:playerController]`), or at least saving it in a strong property. Also your url domain doesn't exist.

Comment: yes alex the problem was player controller was not retaining

Answer (score 0):

You provided URL showing me this message "This webpage is not available

ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED". I tested your code with this URL "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4". It is working fine.

Comment: i think that you don't know stack overflow terms and condition which says dont share server url because it violate security of server.

Comment: I don't know. Thanks.